# Excel's version of group by + having

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Could you please help me with the following.

If Excel table was a relational database table, this is what I would want to do:

[image]

D3 should have a value of 8 and be recalculated whenever rows are added. I am familiar with COUNT/COUNTA and OFFSET functions in case they need to be used. Pivot table will not work, since I don't need all possible A values, just specific one. The solution should work for both Excel and Libre Office. If it also works for Google Sheets, it will be even better.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `sumif`?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula should do the trick:

`=sumif(A1:B6, "=x", B1:B6)`

[image]

You can change the ranges to whatever you need

Comment: Thank you @kaitlynmm569. There following formula worked:
=SUMIF(OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTA(A1:A1000),1),"=x",OFFSET(B1,0,0,COUNTA(A1:A1000),1))
Can it be improved upon?
Is there a generic solution in case SUM() is replaced with another function or formula?

Comment: @Dmitry another option could be to use a query to pull the numbers, and sum the result: `=sum(QUERY(A1:B1000, "select B where A = 'x'"))`.

Comment: Looks like there is no query() function in Libre Office. Thank you.